# What's the name for using a letter to represent its name's sound?

Tags: phonetics, terminology

It's often whimsical to substitute a single letter for a group of letters phonetically identical to the letter's name.

Such as rewriting "barbecue" as "bar-b-q", or the entirety of William Steig's classic children's book [*CDB!* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDB!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDB!).

Is there a name for this phenomenon?

Comment: *Rebus principle* comes immediately to my mind, but this not exactly that what you describe though related.

Comment: I am not familiar with this practice existing or being popular outside of American [English](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Lucian In French this is common (g for j'ai, t for t'es), in Hebrew ז can represent the vulgar word זין. Why do you think this exists only in English?

Comment: @ba: Probably because I am unfamiliar with both French and Hebrew. :-)

Comment: if an abbreviation that uses numbers, such as k9 for "canine", is a [numeronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym), one that uses letters might be called a grammonym